# Laravel Error - "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'staff.staff' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `staff`)"

Tags: laravel

This is my table named "2021_02_17_085102_create_staffs_table.php" and in my database the table is showing

```
    {
        Schema::create('staffs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name')->nullable();
            $table->string('father_name')->nullable();
            $table->string('date_of_birth')->nullable();
            $table->string('age')->nullable();
            $table->string('gender')->nullable();
            $table->string('mobile_number')->nullable();
            $table->string('address')->nullable();
            $table->string('terms_and_conditions')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This is my Model named "Staff.php". I check it 3-4 times but not find the mistake please help me

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'father_name',
        'date_of_birth',
        'age',
        'gender',
        'mobile_number',
        'address',
        'terms_and_conditions',
    ];
```

Comment: did you run `php artisan migrate`  command... and check your database that `staff` table exist or not

Comment: After I php artisan migrate it shows nothing to migrate and I check my database Staffs table is here

Comment: what is your table name `staff` or `staffs` ? add into your model like `protected $table = 'staffs';`

Answer (score 1):

Please specify table name into model just like below.

```
protected $table = 'tablename';
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the error message table name is "staff"

```
select * from `staff`
```

So the somewhere table name is not matched. Simply in your model you can define the table name.

```
protected $table = 'staffs';
```

Then it should be work

Comment: Where system get default value or based on witch logical ?